# Alphabetical sort not being applied to the options of a drop-down during Capybara

Tags: sorting, select, rspec, capybara

My recent changes to alphabetically sort the `options` of a `select` by `first_name` work on `localhost`. However they aren't being applied during Capybara tests.

I'm pretty new to Capybara. Is there anything that would keep the JavaScript function from sorting the options prior to running the tests? As it stands it is just sorting them in the order they were created in the test, as shown below. The `select` menu is a screenshot from Capybara:

[image]
And the JavaScript method from the Backbone view:
[image]

Comment: What is triggering the sorting of the menu?  Capybara doesn't wait for any specific JS to run on the page unless you ask it to wait for something that visibly changes on the page.

Comment: @TomWalpole The sorting is done in within a backbone view. My thought is we know the data is making it from Rails through to the Backbone view through to the HTML, seeing that the names are listed. But they aren't getting sorted in the backbone view before being rendered. At least not in Capybara land. I updated the OP to show the sort method.

Comment: Are you using a Capybara driver that supports Javascript?

Comment: As @PeterAlfvin mentions -- if you haven't configured a different driver (selenium, capybara-webkit, poltergeist, etc), the default driver (rack_test) doesn't have any javascript support so none of the JS would be run